# Rails, Less, and twitter bootstrap can't override nav-tabs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, less, right-to-left

I'm writing a rails application in a RTL language (right to left).
I'm using Less and Twitter Bootstrap for my front-end framework.

To have my site completely RTL I use the CSS files I downloaded and copied from rbootstrap:
  http://rbootstrap.ir/

to assets/stylesheets

Everything works great RTL besides the nav-tabs that are still on the left side.

I tried playing with it a lot and this is what I found:
- If I delete the file bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less a lot of bootstrap's features don't work but the nav-tab does align perfectly to the right.

Every time I try to add something in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less I get the same error:

```
Unrecognised input
  (in /home/bellonet/poligaffes/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less)

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.6.1/html5shiv.js"         type="text/javascript"></script>
       <![endif]-->

       <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

       <!-- For third-generation iPad with high-resolution Retina display: -->
       <!-- Size should be 144 x 144 pixels -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way it worked at the end, was using the original css and js files of rbootstrap directly without less.
That solved it.